# Exception in tearDownDuskClass

Tags: laravel-dusk

**Environment**:

Dusk 5.0.2, Laravel 5.7.28, PHP 7.2.14, PHPUnit 7.5.8, MySQL 5.7, Laravel Homestead, ChromeDriver 2.45.615279

**Problems**:
№1

> Exception in Tests\Browser\::tearDownDuskClass
>   Curl error thrown for http DELETE to /session/e76b9bfe8c9f9af519c2901601531c6a
>
> Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

№2

> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown
>   for http POST to /session/ce9d54d51ec982ff77aa5ca202159ca4/log with
>   params: {"type":"browser"}
>
> Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
>
> Caused by Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl
>   error thrown for http GET to
>   /session/ce9d54d51ec982ff77aa5ca202159ca4/screenshot
>
> Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

**Test class**:

```php
class MyTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations, WithFaker;

    public function testExample()
    {
        $user = \factory(User::class)->create();

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            $browser
                ->loginAs($user)
                ->visitRoute(/**/)
                ->waitForText(/**/)
                ->type(/**/)
                ->type(/**/)
                ->type(/**/)
                ->attach(/**/, /**/)
                ->press(/**/)
                ->waitForText(/**/)
                ->assertSeeIn(/**/)
                ->click(/**/)
                ->assertSeeIn(/**/)
                ->click(/**/); //new tab is opened

            $windows = collect($browser->driver->getWindowHandles());

            //navigate to new tab
            $browser->driver->switchTo()->window($windows->last());
            $browser->assertPathIs(/**/);
        });
    }
}
```

Exceptions are thrown randomly. Usually the very first test after I up my VM is succeed.

Update: temporarily solved using

```
$window = $browser->driver->getWindowHandles()[1];
$browser->driver->switchTo()->window($window);
```

Update 2: even this code at the end of the test cause the error

```php
$browser->driver->switchTo()->window($browser->driver->getWindowHandles()[1]);
$browser->screenshot('scr');
$browser->driver->switchTo()->window($browser->driver->getWindowHandles()[0]);
```

Comment: Have you tried switching backing to the original window at the end of the test?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes (I've just updated the question with this moment).

Comment: What do you mean by "temporarily solved using"?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir it helped for one test execution, all the next test were failed

Comment: Does the test work reliably without the whole "navigate to new tab" part?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes

Comment: Can you create a minimal application to reproduce the issue and upload it to GitHub?